# Bad language translation

Tags: language-support, translation

This is not error or problem, that I need to solve.

When I am using Ubuntu in my language (Slovak) there are sometimes some bad translated words (or at all). Can I some help guys, which are "programing" Ubuntu with that words/sentences?

Answer (score 3):

Those who work with translating Ubuntu into Slovak are the members of the [Ubuntu Slovak Translators team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-sk). You may want to contact them and get involved in improving the Slovak translations.

Generally, if you find a bad translation, you can [submit a bug to Ubuntu Translations](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+filebug).